# bash: how to keep some delay between multiple instances of a script

Tags: linux, bash, queue

I am trying to download 100 files using a script

I dont want at any point of time not more than 4 downloads are happening.

So i have create a folder  `/home/user/file_limit`. In the script it creates a file here before the download and after the download is complete it will delete it.

The script will check the number of files in the folder is less than 4 then only it will allow to create a file in the folder `/home/user/file_limit`

I am running a script like this

```
    today=`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H_%M_%S_%N`;
    while true
    do
        sleep 1
        # The below command will find number of files in the folder /home/user/file_limit
        lines=$(find /home/user/file_limit -iname 'download_*' -type f| wc -l)
        if [ $lines -lt 5 ]; then
            echo "Create file"
            touch "/home/user/file_limit/download_${today}"
            break;
        else
            echo "Number of files equals 4"
        fi
    done

    #After this some downloading happens and once the downloading is complete

    rm "/home/user/file_limit/download_${today}"
```

The problem i am facing is when 100 such scripts are running. Eg when the number of files in the folder are less than 4, then many `touch "/home/user/file_limit/download_${today}"` gets executed simultaneously and all of them creates files. So the total number of files become more than 4 which i dont want because more downloads cause my system get slower.

How to ensure there is a delay between each script for checking the `lines=$(find /home/user/file_limit -iname 'download_*' -type f| wc -l)` so that only one touch command get executed.

Or HOw to ensure the `lines=$(find /home/user/file_limit -iname 'download_*' -type f| wc -l)` command is checked by each script in a queue. No two scripts can check it at the same time.

Comment: This is a bit of a XY problem. The linked duplicate answers X (the problem you actually wanted to solve). This questions is about Y (solving problems in your approach). Just as an extra, here's some information on the Y part: ¶
Adding a delay won't solve the problem. You need a *lock*, *mutex*, or *semaphore* to ensure that the check and creation of files is executed atomically. That is, if one process  executes the part *"check and create files"* other processes cannot execute this part too. GNU parallel comes with the utility `sem` for that.

Comment: I dont want the X way bcause i have to do more things during download not just wget. So can you explain in detail about Y way

Comment: Also for using parallel you have to know the list of items to run parallel before only. here a new script instance can be started and it will also be waiting to touch a file when number of files in the directory are less than 4

Comment: Aside from [bugs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/511004/187122) `parallel` is perfectly capable of working on a list of jobs without knowing the full list in advance. Also, you can execute multiple commands in `parallel` just as you would in your shell, for instance `seq 3 | parallel 'echo 1st step for {}; echo 2nd step for {}'` executes the commands `echo 1st` **and** `echo 2nd` for each input. Anyways, I added an answer for what you asked (even though it might not be the best approach compared to using `parallel` directly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to ensure there is a delay between each script for checking the `lines=$(find ... | wc -l)` so that only one touch command get executed

Adding a delay won't solve the problem. You need a lock, mutex, or semaphore to ensure that the check and creation of files is executed atomically.

Locks limit the number of parallel processes to 1. Locks can be created with `flock` (usually pre-installed).
Semaphores are generalized locks limiting the number concurrent processes to any number N. Semaphores can be created with `sem` (part of GNU parallel, has to be installed).

The following script allows 4 downloads in parallel. If 4 downloads are running and you start the script a 5th time then that 5th download will pause until one of the 4 running downloads finish.

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

main() {
  # put your code for downloading here
}
export -f main
sem --id downloadlimit -j4 main
```

Comment: In the middle of the code how to run part of the code with parallel and capture the return value from that and continue my code from there.

Comment: To do this, your script should have the structure: **(1)** first part **(2)** code from this answer with the middle part inside `main` and with `--fg` added to `sem` **(3)** The last part. ¶ Checking the exit code is a bit tricky. `sem` does not forward exit codes. You can print the exit code and read it (`read code < <(sem … 'main; echo $?')`) or write it to a file (`sem … 'main; echo $? > /tmp/exitcode'`).

Comment: what does `export -f` do.

Comment: I am using `zsh` it says `-f no such option for export`

Comment: Somehow in `zsh` when i do `sem --id downloadlimit  main` it says `zsh:1: command not found: main`

Comment: Asked this as a new question. Can you check it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61948652/zsh-and-parallel-how-to-use-functions-it-says-command-not-found

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi Um, why did tag your question as [tag:bash] when you use [tag:zsh]? I explicitly added the shebang for bash to point out that this script relies on bashisms. I'm no expert in zsh. Hopefully, another user wants to help you with that. Good luck.

Comment: Can i set some priority also eg: `sem --id downloadlimit --priority 100 main` and `sem --id downloadlimit --priority 500 main2`

Comment: How should the priority work? Do you want to pause already running downloads with low priority when a download with high priority wants to start? Anyways, this comment section gets out of hand. Please open a new question for things like that.

Comment: I dont want to stop the existing process, but when it begins a new one it will start the one with priroity first.

Answer (score 0):

My solution starts maximum *MAXPARALELLJOBS* number of process and waits until all of those processes are done...

Hope it helps your problem.

```
MAXPARALELLJOBS=4
count=0
while <not done the job>
 do
 ((count++))
 ( <download job> ) &
 [ ${count} -ge ${MAXPARALELLJOBS} ] && count=0 && wait
 done
```