# zsh and parallel: How to use functions. It says command not found

Tags: zsh, gnu-parallel

I have a script file

filename: `test_sem_zsh.sh`

```
main() {
    echo "Happy day"
}
export -f main 
sem --id testing --fg main
```

I am trying to run it using `zsh`

```
$ zsh test_sem_zsh.sh 
test_sem_zsh.sh:export:4: invalid option(s)
zsh:1: command not found: main
```

It says two error's `1) main command not found` and `2) export:4: invalid option(s)`

Where as when i try with `bash` it works

```
$ sh test_sem_zsh.sh 
Happy day
```

So how to get this script working with `zsh` also

Comment: There is no direct way to `export` function in `zsh`. See this cross-site post on Unix Stack Exchange [what is the zsh equivalent of bash's export -f](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/59360/112235)

Comment: I am running my script as `zsh script.sh`. So is it possible to shift to `bash` for this particular command

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution if you want to use `parallel`, not `env_parallel`:

```sh
function say_hi() { echo -n 'hi '; echo $1 }

F=$(functions say_hi); seq 10 | parallel zsh -c "$F; say_hi $1"
```

The `F=$(functions say_hi)` makes an executable string that can import the function into the guest zsh environment, via `$F`.

Then the actual command `say_hi` is run with an argument `$1`, that is passed by parallel into the guest.

An alternative is to bring it in using `-I{}` like so:

```sh
... | parallel -I{} zsh -c "eval $F; say_hi {}"
```

Comment: I stole this idea from https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/1tqyvzsa6y-using-zsh-functions-with-xargs

Answer (score 0):

Not certain what you are trying to do, but this may help you define a chunk of code you can run under `sem` without needing bash's `export`:

```
#!/bin/zsh

# Create script in /tmp
script="/tmp/tmp-$$"
cat <<EOF > "$script"
echo "Happy day"
date
EOF

sem --id testing --fg /bin/zsh "$script"

rm "$script"
```

This answer is conceptual... for production use, you should set up a `trap` to remove the script, probably use `mktemp` and improve security.

Comment: Why the tempfile? Couldn't you read the here-doc into a variable and pass that to to `sem`? Also, there might be some bugs: I think this is missing a `chmod u+x tempfile`. When writing an actual script into the heredoc, variables might not behave as expected as they are expanded before running the script. Consider using a literal heredoc `<<'EOF'`.

Comment: @Socowi I agree it's not perfect. No `chmod` is necessary as it is executed with `/bin/zsh` rather than via shebang. Agreed OP may want to use a literal heredoc but his example didn't require that. Thank you for sharing your thoughts.

Comment: Oh right, I missed that `/bin/zsh`. Thank you too for posting this answer and being open :)

Comment: Since there is not way to use `zsh` just like `bash`  i am currently using `bash`

Answer (score 0):

`sem` is just a shorthand for `parallel --semaphore`.

You can use `env_parallel`:

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh

# activate env_parallel (if not already done)
. =env_parallel.zsh

env_parallel --semaphore --id testing --fg main
```

Or if your environment is too big:

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh

# activate env_parallel (if not already done)
. =env_parallel.zsh

env_parallel --session

main() {
    echo "Happy day"
}
env_parallel --semaphore --id testing --fg main

env_parallel --end-session
```

Comment: `env_parallel` how this will make change in `zsh`

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi I do not understand what you mean. Try rephrasing - and include an example if possible.

Comment: I mean will the code you showed, will it work when i run the script file using `zsh test_sem_zsh.sh` without giving any error

Comment: Whe try to run your code using `zsh test_sem_zsh.sh` it says `Unknown option: --session` and `env_parallel only works if it is a function. Do the below and restart your shell.`

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi Added activation if you have not already done so.

Comment: please add a simple example of a function that is exported.

Comment: @chovy `main()` is such a function.